# Boost Spirit Expression parser with custom expression class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm working on a test project that will ideally be built into a larger project (wanting to build my own scripting language for fun) in the future that parses expressions into a tree structure using my custom classes.

My expected result is an `Expression` that can be evaluated but the actual result is an expression that has a null `AbstractExpression` pointer.

**Expression Classes**

Note: `State` is a struct that I plan to use to hold variables and other information needed to evaluate

```
class AbstractExpression
{
public:
    AbstractExpression()
    {
    }

    virtual double const Evaluate(State &state) = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractExpression() {}
};

class BinaryExpression : public AbstractExpression
{
public:
    typedef double(*OperatorFunction)(double, double);

    BinaryExpression(char op, AbstractExpression *leftOperand, AbstractExpression *rightOperand)
    {
        this->left = leftOperand;
        this->right = rightOperand;
        this->operatorFunction = GetFunction(std::string(1, op));
    }

    BinaryExpression(std::string op, AbstractExpression *leftOperand, AbstractExpression *rightOperand)
    {
        this->left = leftOperand;
        this->right = rightOperand;
        this->operatorFunction = GetFunction(op);
    }

    ~BinaryExpression()
    {
        delete this->left;
        delete this->right;
    }

    double const Evaluate(State &state)
    {
        return this->operatorFunction(this->left->Evaluate(state), this->right->Evaluate(state));
    }

private:
    AbstractExpression *left;
    AbstractExpression *right;
    OperatorFunction operatorFunction;

    static double Add(double left, double right) { return left + right; }
    //<... A bunch of definitions like the above ...>    
    static double NoOp(double left, double right) { return 0; }

    static BinaryExpression::OperatorFunction GetFunction(std::string op)
    {
        if (op.compare("+") == 0)
        {
            return &Add;
        }
        //<... Lost of else if statements ...>
        else
        {
            return &NoOp;
        }
    }
};

class ConstantExpression : public AbstractExpression
{
public:
    ConstantExpression(double value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }

    ConstantExpression()
    {
        this->value = 0;
    }

    double const Evaluate(State &state)
    {
        return this->value;
    }

private:
    double value;
};

class Expression : public AbstractExpression
{
private:
    AbstractExpression *expression;

public:
    Expression()
    {
    }

    Expression(AbstractExpression *expression)
    {
        this->expression = expression;
    }

    ~Expression()
    {
        //delete this->expression;
    }

    double const Evaluate(State &state)
    {
        return this->expression->Evaluate(state);
    }
};
```

**Parser**

```
namespace Test
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct StatementGrammar : qi::grammar < Iterator, Expression(), ascii::space_type >
    {
        StatementGrammar() : StatementGrammar::base_type(expression)
        {
            expression =
                constant[qi::_val = phoenix::construct<Expression>(qi::_1)]
                ;

            constant =
                qi::double_[qi::_val = &(phoenix::construct<ConstantExpression>(qi::_1))]
                ;
        }

        qi::rule < Iterator, Expression(), ascii::space_type > expression;
        //qi::rule < Iterator, BinaryExpression*(), ascii::space_type> binaryExpression;
        qi::rule < Iterator, ConstantExpression*(), ascii::space_type> constant;
    };
}
```

Below is the code that I'm using to call the parser:

```
std::string string;
Expression exp;

std::getline(std::cin, string);

using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;

Test::StatementGrammar<iterator_type> grammar;

std::string::const_iterator iter = string.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end = string.end();

bool result = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, space, epx);

if (result)
{
    State s;
    double foo = exp.Evaluate(s);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "No Match!" << std::endl;
}

return 0;
```

I'm mostly a C# developer (read: I'm a C++/Boost noob) please correct me on everything I'm doing wrong in C++ (I need to learn where my mistakes are!).

Comment: Thanks @sehe for the link to your answer. I did read through it previously and it's a very detailed answer but I couldn't make sense of all of it, probably due to my lack of experience with C++

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
qi::double_[qi::_val = &(phoenix::construct<ConstantExpression>(qi::_1))]
```

`phoenix::construct` constructs a temporary `ConstantExpression`, whose address is later taken with the operator `&`. Normally taking the address of a temporary results in a compilation error, but most likely this language feature has been lost somewhere inside phoenix implementation. What you probably want to do is:

```
qi::double_[qi::_val = phoenix::new_<ConstantExpression>(qi::_1)]
```

As a side note, `Expression` should probably implement some kind of reference counting of the wrapped expression in order to call `delete` when done. Ideally you don't need ref counting here, since move semantics/unique ownership is sufficient, but I do not believe that Spirit v2 works well with move semantics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. I'm a little fuzzy on how I would make this work with the `BinaryExpression` since it's constructor expects pointers. Would I need to have a constructor that takes parameters by value and makes copies?